# Firebase test lab with iOS app - the app installed but did not open

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xctest, firebase-test-lab

I have a firebase project, I try to run my app in the test lab with a small test that I created, the app installed but when the test lab tries to open the app didn't open and the logs show's the next errors in the logs:

`1."Couldn’t communicate with a helper application".`

`2. "Failed to get automation session for --project name--: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. - ..project local test URL..."`

The Xcode simulator shows me that my test pass and the Archive.zip file added.

If the app will open I think that the test will pass.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please can you provide a matrix-id for your run? The test needs to have run in the last month.

It is also best to use the Firebase Test Lab Slack channel or Firebase Support for these kind of questions about individual test runs.